how to insert an array of json into postgresql column?
create table test (jsonarraycolumn jsonb[]);

insert into test values (array['{"a": 45.50, "b": 10}', '{"a": 70.50, "b": 80}']);

I have created a table 'test'.
Trying to insert an array of json:
1st json:
'{"a": 45.50, "b": 10}'
2nd json:
'{"a": 70.50, "b": 80}'
I am getting the error:
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: column "jsonarraycolumn" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[]
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 26

How is an array of json inserted into a postgresql column?

Do you really want jsonb[]? It's a better practice to declare the column as jsonb, and then store an array json value in it: '[{"a": 45.50, "b": 10}, {"a": 70.50, "b": 80}']

Does this answer your question? What is the use of JSONB[] (JSONB ARRAY) data type in PostgreSQL?

The type of array['...', '...'] is text[]. You need to cast it to jsonb[], just like the error message says:
insert into test values (array['{"a": 45.50, "b": 10}', '{"a": 70.50, "b": 80}']::jsonb[]);

